# How to properly renew Ebay API refresh token

Tags: ebay-api

This morning I got an error accessing the Ebay API saying that my access token is invalid. It's been awhile since I originally generated it (probably the 18 months - sadly I didn't get the actual response from Ebay) so I decided to update/renew the refresh token, which should last another 18 months.

I found this and went through those steps:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-consent-request.html

So I generated the URL and copied it into my browser:
https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=RUNAME&response_type=code&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope...

I approved the request in the browser and copied the resulting URL:
https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&isAuthSuccessful=true&code=v%5E1.1%23...2MA%3D%3D&expires_in=299

In Postman I then created the post (cURL example):

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=v%5E1.1%23...2MA%3D%3D&redirect_uri=RUNAME',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: Basic BASE64(CLIENTID:SECRET)',
    'Cookie: dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**6608a38c^'
  ),
));
```

I am doing this w/in the 5 minutes time the code is valid. All I ever get back is **400 Bad Request**. I tried sending the code the exact way it was returned from Ebay, as well as decoding it and sending it that way.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to using Postman to send the requests. It appears, b/c of various settings, that Postman was URL encoding items when it shouldn't have. So on a whim I tried to run the calls through PHP instead and it worked fine.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$data = [
    'grant_type'   => "authorization_code",
    'redirect_uri' => "RUNAMEHERE,
    'code'         => urldecode('v%5E1.1%23i%5...VeMjYw') // from grant URL call
];

curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($config['app_id'] . ":" . $config['cert_id'])
        ]
    ]
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$results = json_decode($response, true);

print_r($results);
print_r($status);
```

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: Hello Joel,
I have tried with code and getting this error:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"request is missing a required parameter or malformed."}

Do you have any idea why I am getting this one.

That's my code: https://prnt.sc/wSmoQXePZvo-

Comment: @tayeb320 I would make sure the 'redirect_uri' is the correct RU name and that your 'code' value is urldecoded. Your error tells me one of the values in $data isn't correct.